# Android set ImageView's width as a ratio of another element (given the id)

Tags: android, layout

I have an ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/pbc"
    android:layout_below="@id/ryc"/>
```

Is it possible to set it's width to be a percentage of that of another element of id "@id/ryc" just like i've done so in android:layout_below ?If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: Possible in code, not in xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the width in your activity, like the following code (just change `yourPercentage` to the percentage you want)(I have added an id to your imageview, but you can change it):

XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/pbc"
    android:id="@+id/pbcImageView"
    android:layout_below="@id/ryc"/>
```

Activity:

```
float perc = yourPercentage / 100;
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ryc);
ImageView pbcImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pbcImageView);
pbcImageView.setWidth(imgView.getWidth() * perc)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you can put them into LinearLayout and assign proportional weights.

If your design doesn't allow to do so and the size of the views needs to reflect dynamical changes, try overriding [onSizeChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) of one of the views and resize the other in this method. Otherwise giacomoni's answer is the most suitable.